# Invalid literal for int() with base error every time i input any color

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner python programmer. Assistance needed please.

```
lightcolor=int(input("Enter Red,Green,Yellow,White,Purple,Blue,Orange,Brown,or Black->"))
if lightcolor=="Red":
    print("Red Light-Please stop!!")
elif lightcolor=="Green":
    print("Green Light-Please continue")
elif lightcolor=="Yellow":
    print("Yellow Light-speed up")
elif lightcolor=="White":
    print("White Light-its too bright")
elif lightcolor=="Purple":
    print("Purple Light-pretty")
elif lightcolor=="Blue":
    print("Blue Light-thats unusual")
elif lightcolor=="Orange":
    print("Orange Light-bright as the sun")

elif lightcolor=="Brown":
    print("Brown Light-like dirt")
elif lightcolor=="Black":
    print("Black Light-very dark")
else:
    print("Sorry no such color"),lightcolor
```

Why do i get a invalid literal for int() with base error every time i input any color? Am using python 3. Tanks for help I fixed the int and it worked.

Comment: You are calling `int` on your `input()` value, and `int("Red")` isn't valid.

Comment: Because you are trying to convert to an integer a string that isn't parsable as such => `"Red"` or `"Green"` aren't integers!

Comment: Generally, when you're getting an error message and asking a question about it on StackOverflow, it's helpful to actually include the traceback in your question.  In this case, it wasn't actually necessary -- @Blckknght is 100% correct.  What is `int` doing in there in the first place?  Nowhere do you do anything with integers...

Answer (score 1):

`int` attempts to convert the input to an integer, so `int('Red')` will throw a `ValueError`.

You should use `raw_input` instead of `input` and remove the int call:

```
lightcolor=raw_input("Enter Red,Green,Yellow,White,Purple,Blue,Orange,Brown,or Black->")
```

Comment: `raw_input` for Python 2… `input` for Python 3.

Comment: @kojiro no version was specified, and AFAICT most OSes still ship with python2 by default (osx, for example, ships with 2.7.2)

Comment: @Nirk: The parentheses after `print` suggest this user is on Python 3 (though the last `print` is probably not going to work as intended, in that case).

Comment: Would it be possible to add something to the code to change how it responds to a different spelling of the color? For example: if i type in RED, or red and i want it to recognize is as the same.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `int` and making it a `dict` would be the way forward...

```
colours = {
    # List colours... and spelling variations... (put in lower case for easier comp.)
    'red': 'Stop',
    'green': 'Go',
    'black': 'Dark'
}
# Get colour and prompt based on the colours in the dictionary
input_colour = input('Enter a colour (one of: {})'.format('|'.join(colours))
# Try and get description from colours, otherwise use "Not Valid!"
print('That color is:', colours.get(input_colour.lower(), 'Not Valid!'))
```